# Less compiling to empty CSS files

Tags: macos, osx-lion, less

I've been writing less, and using Codekit to compile locally.

Everything compiles to the correct destination as it should.. *but*

Every time I save a less file, it creates an empty CSS file in the same location on my hard disk. This happens when Codekit is closed, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the program itself.

I have no idea what is causing this behaviour, I have no other services running.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For others that get this problem, it's usually a missing or duplicate semicolon on a property or something simple that causes this particular issue. The hard part is tracking down the specific error, so your best bet is to try a couple of different compilers and hope for an error log that tells you at least which .less file is causing the problem. Try node.js with lessc, less.app, winless or whatever else is available to you on your OS. This is a common issues, so it's worthwhile to have another "backup" compiler handy to debug.